# Rails friendly_id gem; Could not find generator 'friendly_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I am running Rails 5.1.5.rc1 and Ruby 2.5.0. Just added the friendly_id gem (`gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0'`) to my gemfile and ran bundle install. I then ran `rails generate friendly_id`

Immediately I get the error "Could not find generator 'friendly_id'. Maybe you meant 'helper', 'channel' or 'mailer'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options."

I can see that the gem was installed.

Anyone know how to solve this or what the issue might be?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you tried bundle install after adding gem ?

Comment: Just in case, try `bundle exec rails g friendly_id`

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Tried both, none works.

Answer (score 0):

if you facing this kind issue for rails generator command. 
run below command in your terminal or command prompt

```
spring stop
```

After this run your generate command